# Conda Snakemake installation issue: UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, snakemake

I am trying to install `snakemake` on linux machine. When running `conda install -c bioconda snakemake` I am getting the error:

> -bash-4.2$ conda install -c bioconda snakemake
>   Solving environment: failed
>   UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>     - backports.functools_lru_cache
>     - snakemake
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Python version is `3.4.5`. OS info:

```
lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1- 
noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1- 
amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core) 
Release:    7.3.1611
Codename:   Core
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

> Update

I tried `conda install -c conda-forge backports`, it installed successfully, but did not help.

> Update

I tried before also using the long command: `conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake` but it failed for some dependencies conflicts. Right now I tried it again and got `unexpected error` of a different kind:

```
-bash-4.2$ conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake
Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
    force_reinstall=context.force,
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 505, in solve_for_transaction
    force_remove, force_reinstall)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 438, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 179, in solve_final_state
    index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 560, in _prepare
    self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 215, in get_reduced_index
    new_records = query_all(spec)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 184, in query_all
    return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 94, in query
    self.load()
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 148, in load
    _internal_state = self._load()
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 222, in _load
    mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 269, in _read_local_repdata
    _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 306, in _process_raw_repodata_str
    json_obj = json.loads(raw_repodata_str or '{}')
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting : delimiter: line 1 column 8388609 (char 8388608)

`$ /sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/bin/conda install -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake`

environment variables:
             CIO_TEST=<not set>
           CONDA_ROOT=/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2

LD_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/slurm/17.02.1b/include:/share/rci_apps/common/inc

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/slurm/17.02.1b/lib:/share/rci_apps/common/lib64
              MANPATH=/usr/share/lmod/lmod/share/man::

 MODULEPATH=/apps/modulefiles/standard/core:/apps/modulefiles/standard/
toolchains



PATH=/scratch/nv4e/cellranger:/scratch/nv4e/bcl2fastq/build/bin:
/scratch/nv
                      4e/spark/bin:/scratch/nv4e/scala/bin:/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/private/bin:/s
                      fs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/bin:/sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/.local/bin:/usr/lib6
                      4/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/sl
                      urm/current/bin:/opt/slurm/current/sbin:/opt/singularity/current/bin:/
                      opt/rci/bin:/opt/rci/sbin:/opt/nhc/current/sbin:/share/rci_apps/common
                      /bin:/share/resources/HPCtools/
       QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins
   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
        SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

 active environment : None
   user config file : /home/nv4e/.condarc
 populated config files : 
      conda version : 4.5.4
 conda-build version : 3.0.27
     python version : 2.7.14.final.0
   base environment : /sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/linux-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                      https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
      package cache : /sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/pkgs
                      /home/nv4e/.conda/pkgs
   envs directories : /sfs/nfs/blue/nv4e/anaconda2/envs
                      /home/nv4e/.conda/envs
           platform : linux-64
         user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/2.7.14 Linux/3.10.0-514.21.2.el7.x86_64 centos/7 glibc/2.17
            UID:GID : 1096641:100
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]:
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if you follow the official installation instructions: http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html#installation-via-conda

You need both -c bioconda and -c conda-forge in the installation command, because some dependencies come from conda-forge.

Comment: Not working, not sure why. I actually already tried that before. Now it is failing with another error than before.

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by (it is `SLURM` cluster):

```
module load anaconda3
conda create -n snakemake
source activate snakemake
conda install -c bioconda snakemake

Use
module load anaconda3
source activate snakemake
```